# how to make echo PHP link

Tags: php

I have a table called as feedback and the table look like this;

```
UserName      image
  abc       image/x.jpeg
  def       image/y.png
```

I want to make a link in php by using echo.

my coding as I try is ,

```
<?php
    require_once('Connections/localhost.php');
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("iis");
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feedback") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo '<a href="'.$row['image'].'">'.$row['UserName'].'</a><br />';

  }


    ?>
```

I want results in a form as below,

```
abc = image/x.jpeg
def = image/y.png
```

so that when you click on the link, it will direct to the folder image and show the image stored by each person.

Comment: In what way is this not working?

Comment: It can show the usernames, but the link it seems not working. I want to create link. I want all the data from column image to be appear as a link

Comment: Can you be more specific?  *How* is the link "not working"?  It looks like an `a` tag to me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: its working bro, using the answer below. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to do this.

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['image'].'">'.$row['UserName'].'</a> </td><td>=</td><td>'.$row['image'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```